# meaning of ちゃってる / chatteiru

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjugations

As far as I know, the sentence "入っちゃってる自分の世界" translates to something like "I'm deep in my own world" or maybe "I went deep into my own world".

What I don't completely understand is "ちゃってる". Is ちゃって like "te shimau" / "chatta" signalling an unintentional/accidental action here? But why "te" and not "ta"? And why "te iru"?

Comment: Do you understand the difference in tense, grammar, and meaning between ～た and ～ている forms?

Comment: It's not quite a sentence, could you include some surrounding texts?

Comment: Yes - I know the difference, but I suppose I've only heard/read "chatta" until now. So "chatteiru" is just the present continuous form of the past "chatta" then? Actually it's from a rap lyric - so grammar could be off..context (first lines only):
う〜入っちゃってる自分の世界 //
う〜オレには誰も見えない //
くらいワールド入っちゃってる

Comment: Listened to the rap.  Technically はいっちゃってる自分の世界 is a noun phrase. It's not a complete sentence. So he hit the gym and trained hard while listening to music on his AirPods at maximum volume. He was so deep in zone that he didn't notice anyone else around him. That's "my own world that I'm deeply in"

Comment: Thanks! What would be a complete sentence the using 入っちゃってる自分の世界?